# Separating while loop tags from each other using (,)

Tags: php

```
while($loop = . . . .){
     $loopy = $loop['tag'];
     echo "<a>$loopy</a>"; 
}
```

Using this code i get the tags outputted like this

```
Tag1Tag2Tag3Tag4Tag5Tag6
```

How do i separate them to be `Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4, Tag5, Tag6`

Comment: You... put a comma and space in the echo?

Comment: @aynber that would make it `Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4, Tag5, Tag6,`

Comment: And then you check to see if it's the end of the loop, or ... actually, hold on, I'll make an answer of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use implode to get that , between the elements.

```
echo implode(', ',array_map($allLops, function($tag){return '<a>'.$tag.'</a>'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a html at the end, so you have to add   at the end:

```
while($loop = . . . .){
     $loopy = $loop['tag'];
     echo "<a>$loopy, &nbsp;</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: Actually this way is the most efficient way I've ever seen, Using HTML instead of PHP, That pretty awesome, But still there is a comma at the last tag

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. A simple one can be:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($loop); $i++){
    $loop[$i] = $loop['tag'];
    echo "<a>$loop[$i]</a>"; 
    // the next line will add the commas but the last one
    if ($i < count($loop) - 1) echo ", "; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array then implode it, like so:

```
$loopArr = array();
while($loop = . . . .){
     $loopArr[] = "<a>{$loop['tag']}</a>";
}
echo implode(', ',$loopArr);
```